# CMake doesn't set Xcode's user include path

Tags: xcode, cmake

When generating an Xcode project with CMake, it doesn't add `/usr/local/include` to Xcode's Header Search Path. Is there a way to fix this in the CMake build file without having to manually change this each time I generate the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that this was easier than I thought, since all I needed to do was a simple:

```
include_directories(/usr/local/include)
```

I ended up going with the following for portability, though I'm not exactly sure if this is much help for non-Linux platforms, anyway:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include)
```